# I need a javascript recursive function that return an array of values when key and json object is passed to this function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I need a javascript recursive function that return an array of values when key and JavaScript object is passed to this function.

Note that the nested JavaScript object has unknown depth. The function is working fine but it returns duplicates.

```
   function getValuesByKey(object, key) {
    var values = [];
    recursiveFx(object);
    function recursiveFx(object) {
      for (var property in object) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          if (typeof object[property] == "object") {
           recursiveFx(object[property]);
          } else {
            //found a property which is not an object
            try {
              if (isDefined(object[key])) {
                console.log('Here is the value that is to be pushed',object[key]);
                values.push(object[key]);
              }
            } catch (e) {

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return values;
  }
```

Here is the isDefined helper function

```
function isDefined(variable) {
    try {
    if (typeof(variable) !== 'undefined') return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Here is an example of JavaScript object:

```
{
      "children": [{
        "id": "5",
        "parentid": "0",
        "text": "Device Guides",
        "index": "1",
        "children": [{
          "id": "10",
          "index": "0",
          "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX"
        }, {
          "id": "11",
          "index": "1",
          "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint"
        }, {
          "id": "23",
          "parentid": "8",
          "index": "2",
          "text": "New Polycom",
          "children": [{
            "id": "5",
            "parentid": "0",
            "text": "Device Guides",
            "index": "1",
            "children": [{
              "id": "10",
              "index": "0",
              "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX"
            }, {
              "id": "11",
              "index": "1",
              "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint"
            }, {
              "id": "23",
              "index": "2",
              "text": "New Polycom"
            }]
          }, {
            "id": "6",
            "parentid": "0",
            "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
            "index": "0",
            "children": []
          }, {
            "id": "7",
            "parentid": "0",
            "text": "Router Setup Guides",
            "index": "2",
            "children": [{
              "id": "9",
              "index": "0",
              "text": "Sonicwall"
            }, {
              "id": "12",
              "index": "1",
              "text": "Cisco"
            }]
          }]
        }, {
          "id": "6",
          "parentid": "0",
          "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation",
          "index": "0",
          "children": []
        }, {
          "id": "7",
          "parentid": "0",
          "text": "Router Setup Guides",
          "index": "2",
          "children": [{
            "id": "9",
            "index": "0",
            "text": "Sonicwall"
          }, {
            "id": "12",
            "index": "1",
            "text": "Cisco"
          }]
        }]}]};
```

When I run this `getValuesByKey(jsonObj, 'id');` I get the following array:

```
["5", "5", "5", "5", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "23", "23", "23", "23", "5", "5", "5", "5", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "23", "23", "23", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "9", "9", "9", "12", "12", "12", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "7", "7", "7", "9", "9", "9", "12", "12", "12"]
```

Notice that 5 has been returned 4 times instead of 2 times

Comment: please show us some nested data and some code you had tried.

Comment: @NinaScholz i have provided the function and json object. it is working fine but it returns duplicates

Comment: If you want it to not return duplicates, please put that information in your question.

Comment: hi @torazaburo I have updated the question

Comment: what is `isDefined(object[key])) ` doing?

Comment: I suppose it would test against undefined/null/etc. What is the exact problem? The function works right?
*edit*: Ah, duplicates

Comment: @NinaScholz have added the isDefined helper function

Comment: @Jad yes yes that is my paradox.... why is it returning duplicates??

Comment: What was not clear in your question is that you want the "real" duplicates to be returned, but there is also a missing condition that makes your code return more of them (see the answers below)

Comment: Thanks @Jad Sorry for making it unclear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are checking for the presence of `key` **each time through the loop** over the object's properties. So you are getting as many values as there are properties on the object. So:

```
function getValuesByKey(object, key) {
  var values = [];
  recursiveFx(object);
  function recursiveFx(object) {

    if (key in object) values.push(object[key]);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for (var property in object) {
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        if (typeof object[property] == "object") {
         recursiveFx(object[property]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return values;
}
```

#### Alternative: use `JSON.stringify` with replacer

Anyway, you can do this more easily with

```
function getValuesByKey(object, key) {
  var values = [];
  JSON.stringify(object, function(k, v) { 
    if (k === key) values.push(v);
    return v;
  });
  return values;
}
```

This uses the `replacer` parameter to `JSON.stringify` to intercept each key value pair. The stringified value itself we don't need and throw away.

Comment: This is not recursive.

Comment: @QuentinRoy Actually, it is.

Comment: @torazaburo I have tested both alternatives and they are working like magic.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @torazaburo

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks that is what i needed

Answer (score 3):

Just an idea of recursion:

```js
var data = { "children": [{ "id": "5", "parentid": "0", "text": "Device Guides", "index": "1", "children": [{ "id": "10", "index": "0", "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX" }, { "id": "11", "index": "1", "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint" }, { "id": "23", "parentid": "8", "index": "2", "text": "New Polycom", "children": [{ "id": "5", "parentid": "0", "text": "Device Guides", "index": "1", "children": [{ "id": "10", "index": "0", "text": "Grandstream GXP-21XX" }, { "id": "11", "index": "1", "text": "Polycom Soundstation/Soundpoint" }, { "id": "23", "index": "2", "text": "New Polycom" }] }, { "id": "6", "parentid": "0", "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation", "index": "0", "children": [] }, { "id": "7", "parentid": "0", "text": "Router Setup Guides", "index": "2", "children": [{ "id": "9", "index": "0", "text": "Sonicwall" }, { "id": "12", "index": "1", "text": "Cisco" }] }] }, { "id": "6", "parentid": "0", "text": "Pre-Sales Evaluation", "index": "0", "children": [] }, { "id": "7", "parentid": "0", "text": "Router Setup Guides", "index": "2", "children": [{ "id": "9", "index": "0", "text": "Sonicwall" }, { "id": "12", "index": "1", "text": "Cisco" }] }] }] };

function getValuesByKey(object, key) {
    var values = [];

    function r(obj) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k) {
            if (Array.isArray(obj[k])) {
                obj[k].forEach(r);
                return;
            }
            if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
                r(obj[k]);
                return;
            }
            k === key && !~values.indexOf(obj[k]) && values.push(obj[k]);
        });
    }

    r(object);
    return values;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getValuesByKey(data, 'id'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: this is interesting. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, there is a bug in your code. You should test that key === property when testing if (isDefined(object[key])) {

Otherwise, you're just adding the matching value whenever you're examining an object that has that value in another property (if that's clear :))

Comment: Thanks @Jad for your help